# Cannot install Prestashop with ProxySQL / MariaDb replication - unable_to_parse_set_statement error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, prestashop, master-slave, proxysql

I am trying to setup a Mariadb replicated environment to scale a Prestashop e-commerce application on multiple DB servers.

My setup :

1 x Mariadb 10.4 Master ,
2 x Mariadb 10.4 Slaves (read-only),
1 x ProxySQL Loadbalancer

I have setup the read/write split by creating a writer_hostgroup
for master and reader_hostgroup for slaves and setup the Mariadb user on the proxy
Connection to ProxySQL is OK and I can perform write/read queries on the cluster
so everything looks well configured to me.

But when I try to install Prestashop by using the proxy
as DB server, installation starts and fail at 23% :

*"It was not possible to install "English (English)" language*

ProxySQL error logs shows :

```
2020-07-15 10:15:47 MySQL_Session.cpp:6483:unable_to_parse_set_statement(): [WARNING] Unable to parse unknown SET query from client 192.168.0.51:47338. Setting lock_hostgroup. Please report a bug for future enhancements:SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
2020-07-15 10:16:33 MySQL_Session.cpp:6483:unable_to_parse_set_statement(): [WARNING] Unable to parse unknown SET query from client 192.168.0.51:47492. Setting lock_hostgroup. Please report a bug for future enhancements:SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
2020-07-15 10:16:43 MySQL_Session.cpp:6483:unable_to_parse_set_statement(): [WARNING] Unable to parse unknown SET query from client 192.168.0.51:47508. Setting lock_hostgroup. Please report a bug for future enhancements:SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

I checked the application and there is actually a

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

query during install.

If I restart the install by using the DB Master node as DB server, everything goes smoothly
(I can also switch the DB server back to the Proxy IP after installation and everything seems to work...).

So is this actually a ProxySQL issue or am I missing something here ?

Comment: What version of ProxySQL are you using?. See [\[WARNING\] Unable to parse unknown SET query after upgrade to 2.0.6](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/issues/2202).

Comment: I am using ProxySQL version 2.0.12-38-g58a909a, codename Truls

Comment: However - Being a totally ProxySQL novice I am still not sure that was the reason that prevented succesfull Prestashop installation.
What does this "lock_hostgroup"  warning means ? Is it preventing the query to execute so it can interfere with actual application ? (in my case FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS variable is not getting updated) ?